# Adjusting bootstrap tooltip data-placement for viewport width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a tooltip that displays right but I want it to display bottom when the viewport is smaller. Crude example here: http://jsfiddle.net/u4krh1we/

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="hi" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="test" title="general kenobi" data-placement="right">hello there</div> 

<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});</script>

#hi {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Was my answer at all helpful? If it solved the problem please accept it as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Bootstrap CSS classes you can show/hide content depending on the size of the viewport by using `.hidden-lg` or `.visible-lg-*` where `lg` can be replaced with any of the bootstrap sizes (`xs`, `sm`, `md`)

Read more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes